# Removing a white page between Appendix heading and Appendix A

Tags: page-breaking, two-column, appendices, article

I tried looking through all the similar questions but couldn't find a similar case. I am writing in article class, this is my preamble:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn]{article}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  
\usepackage{geometry}  
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}  
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}  
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}  
\usepackage{amsmath}  
\usepackage{upgreek}   
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}  
\usepackage{appendix}  
\geometry{a4paper, margin=1.6in}  

\begin{document}

% ... and then the appendix part : 

\newpage  
\appendix  
\appendixpage  
\onecolumn  

\section{Motivation}   
\label{appendixa}

bla 

\end{document}
```

I get "Appendices" in a white page, and only in the next page I get "A AppendixTitle". 
Now, I would like to remove that white space. I have small experience with latex, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the problem is where your `\onecolumn` is - it breaks the two-column setup so should come before your `appendix`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{appendix}

\begin{document}

\lipsum%

\newpage
\onecolumn
\appendix
\appendixpage
\section{Motivation}
\label{appendixa}

\lipsum%

\end{document}
```